# PowerShell Parsing HTML returned search404Captions.content404Title

Tags: html, powershell

I was planning to do a loop on a series of Windows KB websites to grab the names of these KB's

I used inspect and clicked on the text that I wanted so I can see the tag/class names.

```
$geturl = Invoke-WebRequest 'https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4537759/security-update-for-adobe-flash-player'

$geturl.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName('h1')|?{$_.className -like 'c-heading'} | Select *html, *text
```

I got the following results:

> innerHTML   : {{search404Captions.content404Title}}
> outerHTML   : {{search404Captions.content404Title}}
> canHaveHTML : True
> innerText   : {{search404Captions.content404Title}}
> outerText   : {{search404Captions.content404Title}}

I was looking for it to return "Security Update for Adobe Flash Player: February 11, 2020" from this [Microsoft Support Article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4537759/security-update-for-adobe-flash-player).

Can anybody tell me what I did wrong? I tried Googling but didn't see anything useful

Comment: The information you looking for is not part of the HTML document put dynamically prefetched with an anonymous function: `microsoft.support.prefetchedArticle = (function() {
    return { 'en-us/4537759' : {
  "details": {
    "subType": "generic",
    "heading": "Security Update for Adobe Flash Player: February 11, 2020", ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML source code you're retrieving contains *placeholders* for information (`{{ ... }}`), to be filled in later by JavaScript and a *templating library* - the results of which you would see *interactively* in the browser.

(The specific elements you're retrieving are part of a div for error handling (`<div ng-controller="404PageController">`), so they may not be relevant to you.)

However, the information used to instantiate the placeholders with is also part of the page, inside a `<script type="text/javascript">` element, which effectively contains a piece of JSON defining all information elements.

Therefore, you can:

- extract this JSON
- parse it into an object graph with [`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json)
- and access the properties of interest.

**Caveat**:

**The fact that you need to know a potentially page-specific specific search pattern to extract the JSON and to know that JSON's structure makes this a *brittle* approach, as web scraping generally is**. However, it may work for *similar* pages on the same site, assuming they were programmed analogously.

Ultimately, the only *robust* way to retrieve information from sites is via *web services*, not via HTML source code.

```
# Get the target page's HTML source code:
# Note: Since we'll be doing *text parsing* below, we use Invoke-RestMethod
#       rather than Invoke-WebRequest for better performance.
$htmlSource = Invoke-RestMethod https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4537759/security-update-for-adobe-flash-player

# Use the regex-based -replace operator to extract the JSON of interest.
$json = $htmlSource -replace '(?s).+\bmicrosoft\.support\.prefetchedArticle\s*=\s*\(function\(\)\s*\{\s*return\s+(.+?);;.+', '$1' -replace '\}\s*\)\s*\(\s*\)\s*'

# Parse the JSON into a [pscustomobject] object graph.
$dataProperties = $json | ConvertFrom-Json

# Extract the property containing the page title.
$dataProperties.'en-us/4537759'.details.title
```

<sup>Note the top-level `en-us/4537759` property, which suggests language-specific behavior. You may have to use the name appropriate to your system's language.</sup>

The above outputs string `Security Update for Adobe Flash Player: February 11, 2020`, as intended.